# Wordpress uploaded images won't resize

Tags: image, wordpress, resize

When uploading a feature image, it doesn't resize to the size it's supposed to. I've also found when inserting an image into a post and using the percentage resizer, it also doesn't work. What could be causing this? Do you know of a way to fix this?

I'm using a custom theme that was originally modelled off the twenty ten theme.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a piece of code from your template where it inserts a featured image. It's nearly impossible to help you without the code example.

Comment: Where should I be getting this from? Would that be in the functions file?